# Can't access XAMPP over network entirely

Tags: apache, xampp

I can only partially access XAMPP development server over my network.

I am trying to access my main computer from my laptop via http://192.168.0.4/website

The page loads the text only.

**No JavaScript, Images, CSS or Links are rendered.**

When viewing the source of http://192.168.0.4/website from my laptop, I see that all links still have,

```
http://localhost/style.css
http://localhost/javascript.js
http://localhost/image.jpg
```

etc...

These links are not hardcoded as its a Wordpress installation I am trying to access.

Any ideas on how I can correctly access my Wordpress installation on my main computer from my laptop? Is it something in the Apache httpd.conf file I need to edit or...? Got me stumped!

Thanks guys..

Comment: you possibly need to change wordpress config/settings, it think there is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress attaches it's site URL to all links. You installed it on your laptop with "localhost" as the site URL, so that is what is displayed when you look at the site.

Add the following lines (modified for your specific setup) to your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.0.4/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.0.4/');
```

This is a temporary solution. When you are ready to make the site live, change the entries in the wp_options table in the wordpress database, and remove the two lines in wp-config.php.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your reply. Do I need to define these parameters prior to installing WordPress or can I do it after the fact?

Comment: You can define them after installing. Usually they override the values that are in the DB. If they don't in your version of Wordpress, then you need to change the two options directly in the wp_options table.

Comment: This is the output of my source now; `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.0.4/dev/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.0.4/dev/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/dev/wp-content/plugins/meteor-slides/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/dev/wp-content/plugins/meteor-slides/js/jquery.metadata.v2.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>` Somethings changed, some didn't

Comment: Have you disabled and re-enabled your plugins? Cleared your cache? Searched the code for hard-coded instances of "localhost"? If none of that works, try to change the values in the database table.

Comment: Ok I tried a fresh installation and it worked... Thanks Gustav!

Comment: There are no caching plugins etc.. so i think you were right about the wp_options table... sadly theres no easy way to do it on an existing installation.